# How to get color dialog in eclipse during page editing?

Tags: eclipse

i am working on a website which involves a lot of colors and their combinations. but during page designing in eclipse whenever i write color attribute inside the **style tag or in a css file**, i get limited color list, can i get custom color dialog box or hexadecimal values with small preview of colors, that would be helpful during page designing as it would save a lot of time.

Note: recently i have set preferences of colors and fonts for java editor, and i believe this has nothing to do with it.

thanks.

Comment: The CSS editor included in the current Eclipse Web Tools has a button to display the color selection dialog. Web Tools 3.6 part of the Eclipse Luna (4.4) release.

Comment: i am using eclipse oepe-3.8 is there something for this version???